# Get Wrong NSDate out of NSDateComponent with 2011-01-01

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter, nsdatecomponents

I am geting some weird result from NSDateComponents and NSDateFormatter.

I have the following method to set the hour to 10am for the given date

```
+ (NSDate *)getTenOClockOnDate:(NSDate*)inputDate
{

NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar];

NSDateComponents *components = [cal components:( NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSWeekCalendarUnit | NSWeekdayCalendarUnit ) fromDate:inputDate];

[components setHour:10];
[components setMinute:0];
[components setSecond:0];

// construct new date and return
NSDate *newDate = [cal dateFromComponents:components];

NSLog(@"input date: %@ -- new date: %@", inputDate, newDate);

return newDate;
}
```

While I make the following call:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];    
[MyUtils getTenOClockOnDate:[dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2010-12-31"]];
[MyUtils getTenOClockOnDate:[dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2011-01-01"]];
[MyUtils getTenOClockOnDate:[dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2011-01-02"]];
```

only the the second line, I get the unexpected result:

```
input date: 2010-12-31 05:00:00 GMT -- new date: 2010-12-31 15:00:00 GMT
input date: 2011-01-01 05:00:00 GMT -- new date: 2011-12-31 15:00:00 GMT
input date: 2011-01-02 05:00:00 GMT -- new date: 2011-01-02 15:00:00 GMT
```

The problem is on the second record, 2011-01-01, it turns into 2011-12-31 just by setting the hour to 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does indeed look rather odd this... Whilst your code looks like it should be fine my hunch is it's going to be when you're initializing the `NSDateComponents` object you're not enabling the `NSHourCalendarUnit` and `NSMinuteCalendarUnit`.

Whilst you'd think this wouldn't be necessary I think I had a similar issue and found these needed to be on to modify the date's time correctly and get the result you're after.

If that doesn't work, perhaps trying to set the calendar's timezone may be necessary as they're the only differences to what I do and does seem to work a charm.

Comment: Ahhh, well spotted!  I overlooked that one too.

Answer (score 1):

`Println(date)` in Swift is incorrect, use `nsdateformatter` with `stringfromdate`

I guess this apply for nslog too, in Objective-C

Answer (score 0):

This will give right NSDate value from NSDateComponents,

```
NSDateFormatter* df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSDate* date = [df dateFromString:@"2011-01-01"];
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit fromDate:date];
NSInteger day = [components day];    
NSInteger month = [components month];
NSInteger year = [components year];
[df release];

NSLog(@"Day : %d, Month : %d, Year : %d",day,month,year);
```

It will may help you.